# Is there a way to update the data in a row in dataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery and dataTables to display some in a table. Everything works fine but now I need to be able to update a specific row on button click.
To make it clear I attach a screenshot:

[image]

I need when a user is pressing the Cancel button to update the values of this row. Right now I store the values as a data attribute in the `<tr>` element.
I am able to get them but I need to find an elegant way to apply the update.

Does datatables provide some functionality for this?

**EDIT**

When I create the table, I use the createdRow event in order to save the values of this specific element as an data attribute.

```
// add data using DataTable lib
var layer_data = $("#layer_data").DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  "aaData":whole_array,
  "iDisplayLength": 10, // display 10 rows on each page
  // on createdRow add data-initial attribute with the data of the row
  "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
    $.each($('td', row), function (colIndex) {
        $(this).parent().attr('data-initial', data);
    });
  }
});
```

Later I use an on click event (when cancel button is clicked). I retrieve the values stored in the data attribute. I need to put these values back in the cells of the row.

```
// functionality to cancel edits
$(document.body).on("click", "._cancel_btn",function(e){
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').attr('data-initial'));
});
```

Comment: "_To make it clear I attach a screenshot_" ...In my opinion the only thing that can clarify a question on a programming Q&A site is _code_ ...

Comment: @davidkonrad provided some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is straight forward. You have stored an array of strings as `initial-data` attribute on the `<tr>`, these values should be populated to the row columns :

```
$(document.body).on("click", "._cancel_btn",function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
      data = row.attr('data-initial').split(',')

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    table
     .row(row)
     .nodes()
     .to$()
     .find('td:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')') //css indexes is 1-based
     .text(data[i])
  }
})
```

The above works directly on dataTables internal nodes. You could do the same in "pure" jQuery and after that `invalidate()` the row :

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  $('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')', row).text(data[i])
}
layer_data.row(row).invalidate()
```

---

BTW could `createdRow` be improved. You are inserting `data-initial` *n* times (for each column) you only need

```
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
  $(row).attr('data-initial', data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also for the small fix regarding the createdRow. It makes much more sense.